# CSS transparent overlay over Google Maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps

There are the following code:

```
    <div class="google-wrapper">
        <div id="google-map"></div>
        <div id="google-map-overlay">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want that google-map-overlay is over google-map and has red color and I could see google-map, i.e. google-map-overlay should be transparent div. Some styles:

```
.google-wrapper {
    position: relative;

}

#google-map {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 380px;
}

#google-map-overlay {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 380px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute; 

    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

But I don't know how I can do a transparent overlay. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add `opacity` like this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdphr)

```
#google-map-overlay {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 380px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;/*add this*/
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

it offhand, I would like to see exactly what you want to eventually get